# UITableView disable highlight between cell selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

When using `UITableView` with selection enabled, I can select a row and it becomes visible selected with a highlight. However, when I go to select a second row, this is what happens by default:

1. Row 1 is already selected and visibly highlighted.
2. I press my finger down on Row #2.
3. As my finger is still pressed down, both Rows #1 and #2 are visibly highlighted.
4. Releasing my finger now selects Row #2 and only it is visibly highlighted.

What I'm trying to do is make it so in step 3 above, both cells aren't highlighted at the same time. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self.tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return NO;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- Select the table view in storyboard
- Select 'Single selection' instead
  of "multiple selection" in the 'selection' type (in attribute inspector)

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate in this you can unselect the cell.

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Answer (score -1):

OK, I edited this answer based on the discussion.

Assuming you are subclassing UITableViewCell, use this code in the implementation:

(e.g., CustomTableCell.m)

```
#define MyTableCellHighlightedNotification @"MyTableCellHighlighted" 

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style 
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self){
        // Your custom initialization here

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(tableCellHighlighted:)
                                                     name:MyTableCellHighlightedNotification
                                                   object:nil];

    }
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotifcationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    // ...Release ivars...

    [super dealloc]
}

- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL) highlighted
{
    // Default behaviour (defer to super)
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if(highlighted == YES){
        // De-highlight all other cells
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MyTableCellHighlightedNotification
                                                            object:self]

    }
}

- (void)tableCellHighlighted:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    // All cells receive this notification

    if([notifcation object] != self){
        // All cells except the notification sender de-highlight themselves
        [self setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm after. That would mean no rows are selected. Follow the steps I listed to see what I mean. Remember, there's a difference between `highlighted` and `selected`.

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, I'm on an iPhone right now. Tomorrow I can post code if no one else answered.

Comment: If you deselect the row with animated:Yes you can see the fade out (it gets selected and then deselected)

Comment: Again that's not what I'm after. I know it's possible to deselect a cell. I'm not trying to do that. I'm trying to avoid having both cells being **highlighted** at the same time, which is what can happen if one is already selected and you press and hold your finger down on another one. Try it yourself.

Comment: Oh, I see. Try this: keep the selected NSIndexPath on an ivar. When a cell with a different index path is selected, deselect the old one (you have the index path stored so it should be OK) and store the new index path for the next round

Comment: You want a 'toggle' like the buttons on an old car radio, right?

Comment: A new cell does not get "selected" until your finger lets up off of the cell.  It is not selected when you press down it is just highlighted, then it becomes selected when you "touchup" basically.  I read through the documentation and I don't see a clear way to handle this, as the only thing it mentions about highlighting is how to turn it off completely.

Comment: There are 4 relevant delegate methods (willSelect, didSelect, willDeselect, didDeselect) so depending on the timing you want for the switch, some combination should work...?

Comment: Did you try subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding setSelected / setHighlighted?

Comment: Have your cells post a notification when they become highlighted. Also, have them observe the notification. When a cell different than self posts the notification, all cells should respond by de-highlighting themselves.

Comment: I used the method above to impement a clone of Phtoshop's Layers panel in a cocoa app (not UITableView, of course. Used mouse clicks in NSViews instead)